# What is the cause of this ( Timeout: nslookup)?

Tags: perl, dns

I have a server with OS RHEL 6 and Apache/2.2.22, sometime I found this error in Apache error log:

> [error] [client XXXXX] Timeout: nslookup("type" => "MX", "host" =>
> "hotmail.com") at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/Nslookup.pm line 114.
>
> [error] [client XXXXX] Timeout: nslookup("type" => "MX", "host" =>
> "hotmail.com") at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/Nslookup.pm line 114.
>
> [error] [client XXXXX] Timeout: nslookup("type" => "MX", "host" =>
> "yahoo.com") at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/Nslookup.pm line 114.

Is this a DNS problem?

Comment: This question should more properly be on Serverfault, which is the sister site of this one but for server admins rather than programmers. I've flagged it for a moderator to move it there.

Answer (score 0):

It means that something running, probably some kind of mail form running as a cgi, from a web page at your site is getting a timeout when trying to lookup hostnames and is getting a timeout. So yes, that's a DNS problem, probably with the resolv.conf setting for your server.

If you are not aware of any mail form script running on your server, you have a bigger problem on your hands - in that case, you're likely being abused by spammers.